# Line segment and circle collision algorithm

Tags: python, game-physics

My game has a robot that is able to use a laser to kill zombies. I've been browsing the forums for an answer to this question and some people mention projection as the easiest method. I also heard if you make the line segment an actual infinite line that would be easier. If infinite refers to a laser that is so long, that it reaches from one corner of the screen to the opposite corner, then I can do that.  You have to remember this laser is basically a rectangular picture. My robot can also rotate in place so I would want the laser to rotate as well. So basically I want to figure how to detect collision between zombies who will be modeled as circles and my laser which will be modeled as a line segment or infinite line.

Comment: That sounds like some basic geometry would be needed. What have you tried?

Comment: Do this: Work with an actual infinite line. This is basic geometry and you will need to look it up. When you have figured out how to do it math-wise, you can go back to your program and let the line guide your rectangular-picture.

Answer (score 0):

The slow method is by "running a point along the laser, check if it's within reach of any zombies".

```
def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
  """Returns the distance between (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)."""
  return math.sqrt((x2 - x1) **2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)

def check_laser_beam(sx, sy, dx, dy, zombies):
  """Runs a point along a laser beam, checking if it hits any zombie."""

  # Start the laser at the origin
  lx = sx
  ly = sy

  # run a point along the laser, until we hit the edge of the screen
  while onscreen(lx, ly):
    for z in zombies:
       if distance(lx, ly, z.x, z.y) < ZOMBIE_SIZE:
          return z
  return None
```

This is super-inefficient, being essentially proportional to the number of zombies, multiplied by the distance to the screen edge. However, it's simple enough that it can be trivially identified as correct.

It also gives us a hint how to solve this faster. What the above code is doing is to see if the beam intercepts a circle with the radius ZOMBIE_SIZE, centred on any zombie.

We can model the line as a general "a*x + b*y = t" and we can model the perimeter of our circular zombies as "(x - zx) ** 2 + (y - zy) ** 2 = r**2" (only x and y are variables, zx, zy and r are constants). This can be turned into a system of equations, which can be mechanically solved. If you get two solutions, the beam definitely passes through the "circular zombie", if you get one solution, it only tangents the zombie. If you get no solutions, it doesn't intercept the zombie at all.